# Show that $f(x,y)=\sin{(x+y)}$ is differentiable at $(1,1)$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to show this using the definition for differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^2:$

> *A function* $f(x,y)$ *of two variables is differentiable in* $(x,y)=(a,b)$ *iff* $ \ \exists \ $ *constants* $A,B:$
>
> $$f(1+h,1+k)-f(a,b)=Ah+Bk+\sqrt{h^2+k^2} \ \rho(h,k),$$
>   and $\rho(h,k)\rightarrow 0$ as  $(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)$.

I get that

$$f(1+h,1+k)-f(1,1)=\sin(2+h+k)-\sin{2}=0h+(-\sin{2})k+\sin{(2+h+k)} = \\ =Ah+Bk+\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\rho(h,k).$$

Identifying sides I get that $A=0, \ B=-\sin{2}$ and $\rho(h,k)=\sin{(2+h+k)}/\sqrt{h^2+k^2.}$

So the constants $A$ and $B$ are ok, but the trouble now is showing that $$\lim_{(h,k)\rightarrow(0,0)} \frac{\sin{(2+h+k)}}{\sqrt{h^2+k^2}} =0.$$

Comment: Your "identifying sides" step is where you went wrong. Can you elaborate? Why should $A=0$?

Comment: Clearly that limit doesn't equal $0$ as the numerator is going to $\sin 2$ while the denominator is going to $0.$  Use your trig angle addition rules to break up $\sin (2 + h + k)$

Comment: @UmbertoP. - It is my understanding that I'm supposed to write the difference $f(1+h,1+k)-f(1,1)$ in the form $Ah+Bk+\sqrt{h^2+k^2}\rho(h,k).$

Answer (score 0):

$$Df(x_0,y_0)= f_x(x_0,y_0)dx + f_y(x_0,y_0)dy \implies$$

$$  Df(1,1)=
 cos(2)dx+ cos(2)dy = cos(2)(dx+dy)    $$

$$ f(1+dx,1+dy) -f(1,1)-Df(1,1)=$$ $$sin(2+dx+dy) - sin(2) - cos(2)(dx+dy)=$$

$$sin(2)cos(dx+dy)+cos(2)sin(dx+dy) -sin(2)-cos(2)(dx+dy) = $$ 
$$sin(2)[cos(dx+dy)-1]sin(2)+cos(2)[sin(dx+dy)-(dx+dy)]$$

Note that $$ | sin(2)[cos(dx+dy)-1]sin(2)+cos(2)[sin(dx+dy)-(dx+dy)]/ \sqrt {(dx)^2 + (dy)^2}\to 0 $$

That is $f(x,y)= sin(x+y)$ is differentiable at $(1,1)$.